# In MacOS Ventura file system has changed, Apple Menu shut down, restart are not referred from StandardMenus.nib. What is the new way that is referred?

Tags: macos, filesystems, macos-ventura

Earlier MacOS versions taskbar menu were referred from StandardMenus.nib/object.xib. The current MacOS Ventura doesn't have anything mentioned about Shut Down, Restart, Force Quit mentioned under object.xib. Also noted a new file Menus.loctable which has the text referred. How do we see the menu lists in the new MacOS Ventura system?

Comment: Hey @krisdeegee, I am also in search of a solution for this. Did you had any luck ?

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done because Apple has changed the file system in the ventura though you can change edit the strings in menu.loctable using plutil.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).